# Best sql practice for related records

Tags: sql, database-design, join

Hi I need be able to link related applications and am trying to work out the best practice table structure for saving, updating and deleting.

I have the following table:

```
APPLICATION{ApplicationId, Name, Description}
```

I need to be able to say Application 1 is linked to 2 and 3.  Therefore if you open application 2 you'd see that it is linked to application 1 and 3.  Then application 3 is linked to 1 and 2.

What is the best table structure for a linked table?

EDIT

My main query is will I need a record for each join ie for applications 1, 2 and 3 would I need 6 records? 1->2, 1->3, 2->1, 2->3, 3->1, 3->2 ?? If not what is the best query to return all linked apps for a given id?

Comment: You should read 3.3 in this link http://ironbark.bendigo.latrobe.edu.au/subjects/DB/2010s2/lectures/lecture14.html

Comment: Sounds like a tree e.g. [Joe Celko's Trees and hierarchies in SQL](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uw2lq2o4VbUC&printsec=frontcover). Lots of answers here are suggesting adjacency list model but nested sets could be a better fir for you.

Comment: any example implementations of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
application_association
-------------------------
application_1_id
application_2_id
relationship_type
begin_dt
end_dt
```

use relationship_type to specify how the applications are related, and use the dates to specify when that relationship was valid

**edit**:

maybe there is a collective misinterpretation of your use of the word 'linked'.

If you instead mean 'grouped' then you might consider a structure like the following:

```
group
------------------
group_id
name

application_group
-------------------
application_id
group_id
```

here you can just place applications into the same 'group' and then query them all back when they are in the same group.

Comment: ok but to link applications 1, 2 and 3 would I need 6 records? ie 1->2, 1->3, 2->1, 2->3, 3->1, 3->2 ?? If not what is the best query to return all linked apps for a given id?

Comment: Oracle has CONNECT BY, other databases have other means of hierarchic query.

Answer (score 1):

Two more tables.

One for association type:

```
create table ApplicationAssocType
(
    Id int identity(1,1)
   ,[Description] varchar(128) not null
)
```

And one for the association itself:

```
create table ApplicationAssoc
(
    Id int identity(1,1)
   ,ApplicationId1 int not null references Appliation(ApplicationId)
   ,ApplicationId2 int not null references Appliation(ApplicationId)
   ,ApplicationAssocTypeId int not null references ApplicationAssocType(Id)
)
```

[Edit] To clarify, you'd add a record for each individual link. Add any fields to ApplicationAssoc which pertain to the relationship between the applications specified.

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE TABLE AppLink (App1 int, App2 int)`

This is endlessly extendable for as many relations as you need.

Comment: ok but to link applications 1, 2 and 3 would I need 6 records?  ie 1->2, 1->3, 2->1, 2->3, 3->1, 3->2 ??  If not what is the best query to return all linked apps for a given id?

Comment: @moorcroft - no, you could have an `OR` `JOIN` condition `ON t1.id = app1 OR t1.id = App2`...

Answer (score 0):

Application entity has a many to many relationship with itself, so you need another table to store that mapping:

```
APP_Relationship (ApplicationId, RelatedApplicationId)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LinkedApplication{ID, ApplicationId, LinkedApplicationId}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a link table which basically allows you to have a many-to-many relationship between `Application` and itself.

```
CREATE TABLE lnkApplication
(ApplicationID1 int, ApplicationID2 int)

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[lnkApplication]  WITH NOCHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ApplicationLink1] FOREIGN KEY([ApplicationID1])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblApplication] ([ApplicationID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[lnkApplication]  WITH NOCHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ApplicationLink2] FOREIGN KEY([ApplicationID2])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblApplication] ([ApplicationID])
GO
```